# Unable to click links when "position: relative" is used?

Tags: html, css

You can see the issue on the aside here: http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~eeu41f/

I'm using `position: relative` on the aside tag in order to change the `z-index`. However unfortunately this means I can't highlight text or click links on any text placed inside the aside. Removing "position: relative" obviously solves the problem but it means I can't use z-index.

Can you think of any solutions?

```
aside, .top_aside {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -310px;
}


aside {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,200,0),rgb(0,175,0));
    width: 230px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,100,0,1);
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Please include your relevant code here in the question. Anyway, if you can't click a link, anymore, it's probably because your z-index value is too low. The problem is not `position: relative;`, but `z-index`, since the latter requires `position` to be set.

Comment: What links can't you click?

Comment: and add link inside the `li`, not the `li` inside the `a`. It should be: `<li><a href="...">some text</a></li>`

Comment: Its the `z-index:-1;` that is preventing you from clicking the links. Not the relative positioning.

Comment: Also you have invalid HTML in the head of your document. `<h1>
 <div class='logo'>
 <img src="img/LogoTransparentBackground.png" width='706px'>
</div>
</h1>`

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice that syntax error, browsers are too forgiving at times! Thank you very much, solved both issues now, I thought "z-index: -1" wouldn't make a difference, evidently I thought wrong.

Comment: @NylePudding Think of z-index like a stacking order. Z values, or height, for objects is vertical, and you are looking at a computer screen as if looking down into a box filled with stacks of paper. Interactive layers are non-negative; at z-index: 0 and up (0, 1, 50, 9999, all non-negative and therefore "clickable"). Imagine each layer is a piece of paper in the stack, with lower values (z-index: -1) being closer to the bottom of the stack. You can't read what's on the sheet at the bottom (z-index: -1) because there are sheets on top of it (z-index: 5, for example).

Comment: @NylePudding The same is true for clicking. If you interact with elements by clicking them (say, like writing on paper with a red pen), then it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to "click on" (write on w/ red pen) the layer at the bottom (the piece of paper at the bottom of the stack of papers). You'd need to get rid of all the other layers (sheets) that are on top of it, first. You can't do this, however, for all values of `z-index`. Because the browser's base interactive layer is at `z-index: 0;`. It is, in effect, like a glass-bottomed boat. You can stack stuff in the boat and touch it.

Comment: @NylePudding And you can see stuff below the boat, but you can't touch anything under the boat, even if you can see it. Negative `z-index` values are used for hiding all of/part of an element or for depth-related visual effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add to body styles:

```
body {
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a hack but it should do the trick:

Create a `<div>` with the content that is now in the aside, but place it outside of your `<aside>`. Then use relative positioning to move it to the correct position.

Also give your `<aside>` a min-height otherwise it will collapse if empty.

Now the depth effect is retained and the text should be selectable and the links clickable.

css:

```
.pseudo-aside {
width: 230px;
position: relative;
top: 18px;
left: -308px;
}
```

html:

```
<aside>
</aside>
<div class="pseudo-aside">
<p>Hello there, my name's </p>
<hr>
<h1>Llewelyn Gareth Griffiths</h1>
<hr>
<p>I'm currently studying Computer Science at Bangor University. This site is for any odds, ends, games or random things I make in my spare time. Feel free to have a click around or contact me using one of the following methods:</p>
<hr>
<p><a href="#">NylePudding@gmail.com</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/NylePudding">Twitter - @NylePudding</a></p>
<p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/NylePudding">Steam - NylePudding</a></p>
</div>
```